# Need drivers for lg ls720 FOR UBUNTU

Tags: android

I'm looking for the USB drivers for my LG Optimus F3 (LS720) that are compatible with Ubuntu, Linux, Gnome... anything but the .exe files I can get from the manufacturer. I have googled till my fingers bled and all I can find is an exe file. Help a noob out please. :)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief (probably originated when most devices had just a single interface) **drivers** are needed not for the **devices** but for the **interfaces**. And fortunately most interfaces available on Android devices do not require any drivers. But you may need an application to handle proper **protocol** like `MTP` or `adb`